# Remove "x" in bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

So I have this problem. I want to remove "x" in bootstrap tagsinput. This is the bootstrap I use: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/
How do I remove the "x" button? I don't want to affect the other pages that the "x" is removed. Basically, there is a page that "x" button should be remove and there is also another page that "x" should not be removed. How to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: I would use JavaScript to insert a class for the `x`s on a particular page then just remove all the `x`s with that particular class on that page.

Answer (score 3):

Add Following CSS to the page you want to remove "x" from

```
    .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
       content: "";
       padding: 0px 2px;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Here is link to the demo https://jsfiddle.net/3gth/7m3zwLos/